# Route post does not respond on laravel 7

Tags: axios, laravel-7

I use laravel 7 with the framwork view js using the axios package. When I compile the **addex** method in post mode via the route above I receive this while the route is declared in post mode in the web view.

Here is my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I click on button 'add' it gives me page **404** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Route Facade in your web.php code means:

so remove
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route`

And with `php artisan route:list` command in your terminal you can see your active and overwrited routes and know if your route not defined.

Comment: when i put this order php artisan route:list
the road exists but it shows me a 404 page

Comment: Do you Removed Route Facade from top of web.php? @karzazi0124

Comment: Yes. Because its wrong to use Route Facade there @karzazi0124